# Should'nt there be a feature in AU that would allow a user to get notified about changes in questions or answers he/she upvoted or downvoted?

Tags: support, feature-request

Lets say I up vote a question since I felt that I had faced a issue earlier similar to that which was mentioned in the question. Now, when someone comments in it or answers the question I may also want to be notified. Also I may have up voted a question before an edit. After the edit I may want to down vote it. So will AU notify me about all this?(So in general, will AU notify me about changes that occur in a question or answer to which I voted?)

Update :- As it is clear from the answers below AU doesn't do so. But I feel that AU should have such a feature. Therefore I want to make this question into a **"FEATURE REQUEST"** Therefore now, does the community feel that AU should have this feature?

Comment: Having it automatically do this on votes would have limited value to many users, as the answers to the question Braiam mentioned state - though a separate "subscribe" button wouldn't be half bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no

Long answer: there is a feature request already about it [Notify me of edits to posts I've voted on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68106/213575)